# Script out the text in all stored procs in database

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Is it possible to script out all of the stored procedures in a database? By script out, I mean the entire text (e.g. `CREATE PROCEDURE ...... SELECT` and all of it).

Datbase is SQL Server 2008 r2.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to do it pragmatically (SQL only or .NET) or via interface?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes you can. just right click on the `DataBase > Task > Generate Script`

It will launch a wizard where you can select the Objects you want to script (in this case select all store procedure)